# Pandas applymap loops twice, apply once?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Want to only use the first email if multiple are added. Made a function which looks for ',', if it finds it, displays a message and returns the first email.
For a strange reason, it seems to loop through the dataframe twice when using 'applymap', because it prints the message twice.

When I use the 'apply' function on the series, it -as expected-prints out once. Any idea why is this discrepancy?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation, version 0.25.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), I quote :

> #### Notes
>
> In the current implementation applymap calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.